# Why does UIAlert generated by UILocalNotification display "Options" instead of action title?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-watch

I am trying to set up an Apple Watch app (presenting flashcards) which fires a notification when a new question is due. If the iPhone is open but the app is in the background it fires a UIAlert, and clicking the action button ("View") opens the app. If the iPhone is locked the notification fires on the Apple Watch with a short glance-long glance with a button "View Question" which opens the Apple Watch app.

It works, but the UIAlert on the iPhone has an annoying "Options" button which requires you to click "Options" to open another UIAlert with two action buttons ("View" and "View Question"), either of which will open the iPhone app. Here is the relevant code which first cancels all previous notifications (as the app allows you to answer a new question before the timer is finished, at which point the timer is reset). It then sets up a notification to be displayed on the iPhone; and finally sets up a notification for the Apple Watch.

```
// Cancel previous notifications
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

// Set up iPhone notification
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(int)dateLatency];
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger intVal = [prefs integerForKey:@"timeLag"];

localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld-%d", (long)intVal, (int)dateLatency];
localNotification.alertAction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"View"];
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

localNotification.alertLaunchImage = nil;

localNotification.category = @"qDue";
localNotification.userInfo = [self createAPNS:@"999"]; // function that constructs userInfo json structure    

// Set up apple watch notification
NSMutableSet *categories = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *viewQuestion = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
viewQuestion.title = @"View Question";
viewQuestion.identifier = @"viewQuestion";
viewQuestion.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
viewQuestion.authenticationRequired = false;

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *questionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
questionCategory.identifier = @"qDue";
[questionCategory setActions:@[viewQuestion] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

[categories addObject:questionCategory];

UIUserNotificationType notificationType = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:notificationType categories:categories];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

// Schedule it with the app
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

I can get rid of the "Options" button and the extra UIAlert by deleting the apple watch notification, but then there is no notification on the apple watch.

Can anybody tell me why the "Options" button appears, and how to get rid of it?